# How can i join two paths without losing round edges of one path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

[image: Image showing the round corners at the bottom]

I have created the round corner at the bottom by using scissor tool to cut the upper part(which is shown blue in the image) and use 'Effetcs> Stylize> Round Corners' at the bottom path

But now when I join it back by 'selecting both the paths> right click> join' or by 'path finder> unite' every time I lose the rounded corners at the bottoms

Comment: You should menu Object > Expand the bottom shape before joining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an easier way to create a shape like that.

Draw a rectangle

Choose the Anchor Point tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Mouse over the centre of the top path until the little bend icon appears

Begin clicking and dragging upwards, then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while continuing to drag.

[image]

The rounded corners at the bottom can be created using the rounded corner widgets (available in Illustrator CC only).

[image]

Comment: I couldn't see any bend icon when I hover the upper line of my rectangle with 'Convert anchor point tool (shift + C) '... neither do I see those small circles from the second image. It seems like I'm missing a little important step here!

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh What version of Illustrator are you using?  I think it only works in Illustrator CC.

Comment: It is Adobe illustrator CC... version 17.0.0

Comment: Perhaps you'll need to update to the latest version which is 22.1 - that's the version I'm using.

Comment: Yes, upgrading the illustrator did work!